# Finding the largest value in column based on date in other column?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and am trying to find the largest value for cells that contain a specific year.
Example:

```
A            B
DATE         Value
1 jan 1875   4000
1 jan 1880   800
5 feb 1875   3500
6 jun 1875   2500
```

I have read about the MAXIFS function but am unsure how to apply it in this situation.

MAXIFS(B2:B4;A2:A4;1875) only returns "0" when I want it to return "4000" in B2.
I have tried substituting the "1875" in the formula with "YEAR(1875)" but it doesn't work.
It might be an issue with the dates being before 1900 but I've tried using years after 1900 as well, still it won't work.

Anyone here who knows?

Comment: An ugly solution is to use create a C-column and using Text(A2;"YYYY") to create a text string saying "1875" and then running MAXIFS(B2:B6;C2:C6;"1875"). This will yield "4000" as the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a query instead of MAXIFS:

```
=query(A:B,"select max(B) where A contains 1875")
```